# REST API Logs in Azure

Tags: azure

Is there anyway to see all requests done via REST API?

I want to be able to monitor REST API calls done by a client ID.  I want to look into what specific APIs were called, if possible how the request/response looks like for each call.

Comment: this is where you need to put some kind of monitoring inside your code. I dont think Azure has built in capabilities for tracking specific REST API calls. Application Insights can be customized to do this, yes, but not out of the box. Or, you could just build your own custom logging which is what I would do, have done.

Comment: I was able to talk to Azure support and looks like there is indeed no built in solution for this. looks like I have to customize it as suggested. thank you!

Comment: let me put that has an answer then. it will be useful for future question posters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just posting this here to help future question posters.

*this is where you need to put some kind of monitoring inside your code. I dont think Azure has built in capabilities for tracking specific REST API calls. Application Insights can be customized to do this, yes, but not out of the box. Or, you could just build your own custom logging which is what I would do, have done*

The OP has confirmed that this is indeed the case with Azure, after he spoke with the Azure support folks.

Answer (score -1):

I hope you are talking about a web app or a mobile app calling a backend app which is running on azure or somewhere else. So for this the answer is using [Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/app-insights-overview), it is now part of Monitor but built for apps to monitor APM (Application Perf Monitoring).