# How can I view logs from Azure REST API requests?

Tags: azure, azure-rest-api

Assume I send a request to the Azure REST API:

```
az rest 
  --method GET 
  --uri 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/000000-00000-00000-00000' 
  | ConvertFrom-Json
```

If a request fail I get an error message:

```json
{
    "error":
    {
        "code": "Request_BadRequest",
        "message": "One or more properties contains invalid values.",
        "innerError":
        {
            "date": "2022-10-07T06:12:04",
            "request-id": "111111-2222-3333-4444-5555555",
            "client-request-id": "12345-1234-1234-1234-12345678"
        }
    }
}
```

How can I view the log that is referenced with `"request-id":"111111-2222-3333-4444-5555555"` or `"client-request-id":"12345-1234-1234-1234-12345678"`?

Comment: Please check if this helps [REST API Logs in Azure - Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/101874/rest-api-logs-in-azure.html)

Answer (score -2):

1. There is no inbuilt resource to log the requests coming to Azure rest api.
2. Refer to one of the similar [issues](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63952952/16630138) regarding REST APIs using in Azure.
3. Application insights can be used for tracking purpose if your application is deployed in azure.
4. Created the Web App > created & configured application insights resource:

[image]

5. Go to Overview blade of Web App > `requests` coming to web app in a graphical representation:

[image]

6. To view logs of webapp, go to web app and click on Logs in Monitoring session.

Example: Below is one failed request to web app can be seen in logs,
[image]

Refer to this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/app-insights-overview?tabs=net) for more information on Azure Monitor App Insight Logging.